# Using Broadcast variable OR using RDD filter for computing intersection of two nodes neighbors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

i have used GraphLoader to load my graph into RDDs. each node in graph has some neighbors. the main goal is to find their intersection and do some parallel and distributed operations on them.
each node at first has attribute 1 and i have changed their attribute to be (label,Isimportant) by using below code:

```
case class nodes_properties(label:Int, ISimportant:Boolean=false)
var work_graph=graph.mapVertices{case(node,property)=> nodes_properties(node.toInt,false)}
```

every time any node updates its label, the work_graph will be updated.

i have used 2 methods for finding common neighbors (intersection of 2 nodes neighbors set) of two nodes. i should mention that i will execute them on a cluster not local.

```
neighbors(1)=[2 3 6 9]
neighbors(2)=[1 3 5 9]

intersection(1,2)=(3 9)
```

**first method :**

```
val all_neighbors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).cache()
val broadcastVar = all_neighbors.collect().toMap
val nvalues = sc.broadcast(broadcastVar)

val common_neighbors=nvalues.value(1).intersect(nvalues.value(2))

common_neighbors.foreach{ 

work_graph=work_graph.mapVertices((vid:VertexId,v:nodes_properties)=> {
 x=>

 if(vid==x) nodes_properties(core_node_label)
 else v })
}
```

**Second method:**

```
val all_neighbors: VertexRDD[Array[VertexId]] = graph.collectNeighborIds(EdgeDirection.Either).cache()
val common_neighbors2=(all_neighbors.filter(x=>x._1==1)).intersection(all_neighbors.filter(x=>x._1==2))
common_neighbors2.foreach {

work_graph=work_graph.mapVertices((vid:VertexId,v:nodes_properties)=> {
 x=>

 if(vid==x) nodes_properties(core_node_label)
 else v })
}
}
```

**Question:**

my question is this: **which of the above methods run in parallel and distributed way???**. i mean if i use method 1 and the broadcast variable for computing common neighbors, will the foreach method for doing some operations run in all slaves and distributed way or if i use method 2 and use filter for computing common neighbors and then doing foreach will be run in distributed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, none of the methods will be run in parallel

First method, it will be executed on the location of graphs but in sequential way because you call `foreach` on scala `Map`

Second method, I guess it should execute filtering in parallel (sorry, I didn't work with GraphX), and then it'll get into sequential `foreach` execution

It's also noted at [Spark's GraphX doc page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/graphx-programming-guide.html) that

> Note that *collectNeighborIds* and *collectNeighbors* operators can be quite costly as they duplicate information and require substantial communication. If possible try expressing the same computation using the **mapReduceTriplets** operator directly.

I would suggest to re-arrange your code accordingly to advice above, map reduce  (I'm referring to `mapReduceTriplets`) will be executed in parallel and distributed way for sure

Comment: in first method i have used toMap  to make the collection to become as key,value and broad cast it. i have used broadcast to copy neighbors collection to each slave in order to decrease communication between slaves and driver. in second method you mean that foreach does not execute in parallel? in second method the common_neighbors2 is and RDD and i think calling foreach on RDD executes in parallel. am i wrong?? i am really confused with this part of algorithm.

Comment: if i use aggregateMessages for cellecting each nodes neighbors instead of collectNeighborIds and collectNeighbors, would it have good performance than collectNeighborIds and collectNeighbors??